# Set default username in TWTweetComposeViewController from ACAccount

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, twitter, account

i am using `TWTweetComposeViewController` and there are more than one accounts in my twitter setting (twitter from Setting in your device), it is showing a picker so from that we can select any username, and by default it is getting first username from your accounts as showing in `image`
[image].

> Now , i want to set any of my accounts to the default  and not want to
>   show picker. is it possible ?

i am aware of ACAccount framework , which contains array of my different Twitter accounts , so i can get different usernames from it.

**OR**

> it there any way to get username when i select any of username from
>   the picker in `TWTweetComposeViewController`.

Answer (score 3):

You can not specify the twitter account when presenting the `TWTweetComposeViewController`. The user must select it from the list when he has more than one account. You can only detect if there is at least one account with `canSendTweet`.

If you really want to preselect an `ACAccount` beforehand you need to use a lower level API, namely `TWRequest` (`SLRequest` in iOS 6) and create the UI yourself. With this class you can set the account (property) which is used for the tweet request and you can do way more than just tweeting.

Comment: currently i am doing Retweet , Favorite and Reply with ACAccount framework with the help of TWRequest , and from this framework i am getting array of different twitter accounts , so similar thing is not possible with TWTweetComposeViewController?

Comment: At least not using public methods.

Comment: @FabianKreiser i am not understanding your comment.